# does angularjs have some tech like fetch().blob

Tags: javascript, angularjs

calling $http.get() for audio/mp3 file

from chrome network response I see response data looks like this:

"ID3"TSSELavf56.4.101ÿû@ÀInfo\Ê

"$'),.1469<>ACEHJMORUWZ]_bdgilnqsvx{~¢¤§©¬®±³¶¸»½ÀÃÅÈÊÍÏÒÔ×ÙÜÞáäçéìîñóöøûýLavf56.4.101$ÿûPÄÀ¤ 4LAME3.98.4UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUULAME3.98.4UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUÿûRÄ]À¤"

I do not download or play.

But with Javascript  fetch().blob()
I could convert it to Blob
from fetch(response)  I know the data type is ReadableStream

My question is, how could I use angularjs to handle this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to Download Binary Files with AngularJS

When downloading binary files, it is important to set the `responseType`:

```
app.service('dataService',['$http',function($http) {

    this.downloadFile = function(url) {

        var config = {      
            //SET responseType
            responseType: 'blob',
        };

        return $http.get(url, config);
    } 
]);
```

If the `responseType` is omitted the XHR API defaults to converting [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded text to [DOMString (UTF-16)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) which will corrupt PDF, image, and other binary files.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR ResponseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

Comment: it works, thank you very much